# How to restrict search of function maxlik in Matlab to real numbers?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the [maxlik](http://www.spatial-econometrics.com/optimize/maxlik.m) function of Econometrics Toolbox in Matlab. For some reason, the function reports as final results imaginary numbers (e.g., -6.4637 + 1.8930i) instead of real numbers.

Is it possible to restrict the search only to real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose b is the vector of parameters you are trying to estimate using the maxlik function of Econometrics Toolbox in Matlab. You can restrict the research to a specific space (i.e. [-10,10]) by imposing the following restrictions:

```
b(b>10)=10;
b(b<-10)=-10;
```

You will need to embed this restriction in your code as maxlik function doesn't have a way of restricting the search space.